# Is there a difference between “after 3 days from the date” and “3 days after the date”?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions

I received a message from bank regarding a transaction I made. The line was:

> please raise dispute **after** 3 working days **from** the date of transaction

If I were to send this, I would have written:

> please raise dispute 3 working days **after** the date of transaction

Are the meanings of these two lines the same? I believe the meaning of both the lines are that the dispute should be risen if transaction is unsuccessful after 3 days have passed. I have always seen the latter being used. Is former different because it is formal?

Comment: Yes, they mean the same thing. "after" there works like "within", though with a different meaning. With "after", you have to wait 3 days before filing a claim. With "within", which is more normal (there's no reason for having to wait), you have up to 3 days to file the claim.

Comment: Both versions are not quite right. Also, raising a dispute may have nothing to do with "transaction is unsuccessful." One reason to wait three days is that some oddities disappear by then, so that a dispute is a waste of time. An example is a test transaction to see if the account number is correct. Another is an error like a duplicate charge that the bank catches by itself in a day.

Comment: No, they don't mean the same thing. The first means 3 days ***or more*** after the transaction; the second means ***exactly*** 3 days after the transaction.

Comment: @jasonBassford can I take another sentence. For example- "his exam was over on 16th, he came 3 days after the exam got over" and "his exam was  over on 16th, he came after 3 days from the date of over of examination" does the former mean that his exam was over on 16 and he came exactly on 19th. And latter means his exam got over on 16th and he came anytime after 19th. Is my logic right ?

Comment: @AkshitRaj Yes, that's right. Although both *could* be interpreted to mean the other, it's more common for them to be interpreted in those differing ways.